# jQuery code optimisation: Can i write this in one line?

Tags: jquery

can i wrote this two lines of jQuery code in one line? How?

```
$('#title').hide().delay(4000).fadeIn(100);
$('#titleNew').show().delay(4000).fadeOut(100);
```

Comment: Changing something into one line is not an optimization. Optimization is when you **after** some profiling find the slowest part that is *required* to be optimized and modify it somehow. It may change the code to become even longer. So - being one line doesn't mean it will run faster than 10 lines

Comment: I think this is the clearest way to write this. I would not write this in one line since your code will be less readable.

Comment: Regardless of whether you could, I don't think you should.. You're doing two different operations on two different elements.

Comment: I beleive you can do `$('#title, #titleNew').show().delay(4000).fadeOut(100);` if you wanted it all on one line. Right?

Comment: @Dan he wants to hide #title and show #titleNew, so that won't work. I agree with others, I don't think this should go in one line (even if it could) because of readability and because you're doing two different things. Putting it in one line would be the opposite of optimization.

Comment: does not works as two lines :/

Comment: So, your original code doesn't work? how can you expect us to help you "*optimize*" broken code?

Comment: Code works fine, i just wish to write in one line... if it is possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes you can.

```
$('#title,#titleNew').toggle().delay(4000).fadeToggle(100);
```

or

```
$('#title').add('#titleNew').toggle().delay(4000).fadeToggle(100);
```

Do not look at this as an optimization, it's simply a different way of writing it. Since you're only dealing with two elements and you're selecting them by id, there is no optimization to be made.

the second may be ever so slightly faster than the previous due to not using the css selector engine, but it comes at the cost of readability. **Both of these are likely slower than what you already have**.

Comment: Kevin, did you mean `$('#title').toggle().add('#titleNew').delay(4000).fadeToggle(100);` instead ? - http://jsfiddle.net/qRqLD/

Comment: Hmmm, true. I leave my comment, just to warn OP and give a +1 to you `^-^`